# Cross-platform (Linux, BSD, Solaris) way to check if pid exists

Tags: process, kill, process-management

I am looking for a reliable cross-platform way to check if a process with a specific pid is running.  Two possible solutions came up:

1. `kill -0 $PID` — exit status is 0 if it the process exists and 1 if not, however it also returns 1 for pids that require additional privileges to kill.
2. `ps a | grep "^\s*${PID}"` and similar which are plain ugly.

Is there a way to have something like #1, but without the owner limitation?

Comment: Note that knowing that a process isn't running isn't very useful, because by the time you do something with the result the process may be dead, and may even be a different just-started process after the prior process with the same PID died. The only time you can rely on a PID being meaningful is from its parent, until the next time you call one of the `wait*` functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you write a small C program?  The `kill(2)` system call does return -1 if your UID doesn't have permission to send a signal to a given process, but `errno` is set to `EPERM` in that case, as opposed to `ESRCH` for a non-existent PID. I'm reasonably certain you could make it portable across Solaris, HP-UX, Linux and the *BSDs.  You would have to compile it for each platform.